# Fusion table stopped appearing via Maps API (fusiontablelayer)

Tags: google-fusion-tables

A fusion table has stopped being shown via the Maps API. It was working the other day (Monday or last Friday).

It works fine inside the Fusion Tables website.

Other fusion tables continue to work fine via the Maps API.

Here's a site I made showing the (actually not showing the) layer in question.

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14878119/map/sewerlayernotshowing.html

View the source of that site for the entire code, but here's how this layer (and all the others we use) are being called:

```
<script>
        //initializing Google Maps              
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('divMap'), {
                zoom: 14,
                center: {lat:33.040171488300871,lng:-97.022509084376622}
            });
        //Fusion Table (Sewer Lines) *****NOT WORKING!*****
            var _ftId = "140ge-x0HKkzrlZYOdrCxYBNlu4ta15vpHetZh_s";
            var _ft = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(_ftId,{query: "SELECT * FROM " + _ftId});
            _ft.setMap(map);

        //Fusion Table (Sewer Points) *****WORKING*****
            var _ftId2 = "1NsByxnFPfr20fL1MAr_zYoPdtocKqCXJg9tqLoA";
            var _ft2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(_ftId2,{query: "SELECT * FROM " + _ftId2});
            _ft2.setMap(map);
    </script>
```

Any ideas why the one with id 140ge-x0HKkzrlZYOdrCxYBNlu4ta15vpHetZh_s would stop working?

Comment: Need more context. That code works fine wrapped in an initialize function and run once the document load event fires.  Can't see dropbox files.  [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MJq2J/)

Comment: The second fusion table does work correctly. Its the first one that does not.  The dropbox url works for me...It should show a blank/plain google map with no fusion table because that fusion table layer won't load for some reason...

Comment: dropbox is blocked by the corporate firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the "old" (now undocumented) syntax for [FusionTableLayer constructors](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayer).  Use the new syntax and it works.

```
//Fusion Table (Sewer Lines) 
var _ftId = "140ge-x0HKkzrlZYOdrCxYBNlu4ta15vpHetZh_s";
var _ft = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
     query: {
        select: "Shape",
        from: _ftId,
        where: ""
      },
      options: {
        styleId: 6,
        templateId: 2
      }
    });
    _ft.setMap(map);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MJq2J/2/)